# Dictionary with tuples as values

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to create a dictionary like this in Python?

```
{'string':[(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)], 'string2':[(a,b),(z,x)...]}
```

The first error was solved, thanks!
But, i'm doing tuples in a for loop, so it changes all the time.
When i try to do:

```
d[key].append(c)
```

As c being a tuple.

I am getting another error now:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Thanks for all the answers, i managed to get it working properly!

Comment: You wrote `d.append(c)`, but I think you meant `d[a].append(c)`.

Comment: Yes, i realized that it was a simple syntax error! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to construct the dictionary in that fashion?  You could simply define

```
d = {'string': [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')], 'string2': [('a', 'b'), ('z', 'x')]}
```

And if you wanted a new entry:

```
d['string3'] = [('a', 'b'), ('k', 'l')]
```

And if you wish to append tuples to one of your lists:

```
d['string2'].append(('e', 'f'))
```

---

Now that your question is clearer, to simply construct a dictionary with a loop, assuming you know the keys beforehand in some list `keys`:

```
d = {}

for k in keys:
    d[k] = []

    # Now you can append your tuples if you know them.  For instance:
    # d[k].append(('a', 'b'))
```

There is also a dictionary comprehension if you simply want to build the dictionary first:

```
d = {k: [] for k in keys}
```

---

> Thanks for the answer. But, is there any way to do this using
>   defaultdict?

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in 'string1','string2':
   d[i].append(('a','b'))
```

Or you can use `setdefault`:

```
 d = {}
 for i in 'string1','string2':
     d.setdefault(i, []).append(('a','b'))
```

Comment: Yes, i need to construct the dictionary doing a for loop, and I just don't know how many keys would be there. So i could not define the keys first.

Comment: I see, I didn't quite understand your question.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, is there any way to do this using defaultdict?